# Chrome Browser Issue for Button

Tags: javascript, rally

I have an issue with a Button. It is appearing in IE and Firefox, but not appearing in Chrome.

The code for the button is using Rally API and it’s  generated while loading the page.

I have tried Googling the answer, but I couldn't find anything.

Heres my code:

```
function onClick(b, args) {
    if(OneButtonClickFlag == true) {
        OneButtonClickFlag = false;
        var buttonValue = args.value;
        var userName = "__USER_NAME__";
        TimeSheetReport(); // calling the “timesheet report “

    }
}

function onLoad() {
    var config = {
        text: "Generate",
        value: "myValue"
    };

    var button = new rally.sdk.ui.basic.Button(config);
    button.display("buttonDiv", onClick); // call the “onclick” function 
}

rally.addOnLoad(onLoad);
```

Answer (score 0):

This App below seems to work with your code in it up until the point where it encounters your OneButtonClick flag. I tested it in Chrome. Does this work for you?

```
<head>
    <title>Button Example</title>
    <meta name="Name" content="Component Example: Button"
    />
    <meta name="Version" content="2010.4" />
    <meta name="Vendor" content="Rally Software" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/1.26/sdk.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onClick(b, args) {
            console.log("works until this undefined variable");
            if (OneButtonClickFlag == true) {
                OneButtonClickFlag = false;
                var buttonValue = args.value;
                var userName = "__USER_NAME__";
                TimeSheetReport(); // calling the “timesheet report “

            }
        }

        function onLoad() {
            var config = {
                text: "Generate",
                value: "myValue"
            };

            var button = new rally.sdk.ui.basic.Button(config);
            button.display("buttonDiv", onClick); // call the “onclick” function 
        }

        rally.addOnLoad(onLoad);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="buttonDiv"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: yes this code is working fine in IE and Mozilla.only problem is with Chrome .So do i need to change the code or let me know any suggestions .

Comment: var OneButtonClickFlag is a global variable

Comment: My example works fine in Chrome for me. Does it work for you?

Comment: actually its working in chrome...but problem is some times button is disappering ...so need solution for that ...its happening while we add this javascript code in Rally tool.